# GAE MapReduce - Use file from html form input

Tags: python, google-app-engine, mapreduce

I would like to perform a mapreduce job with the following steps:

1) Map from file that is input via html form

2) Reduce and create new file from reductions

Here is how I currently have my pipeline setup. The main question is how do I pass the file to the RecordsReader.

The RecordsReader has a parameter files which is to be passed "Either a string containing the file to be read or a list containing multiple strings of files to be read." -Google

```
class EPNPipeline(base_handler.PipelineBase):
    def run(self, filekey):
        logging.debug("filename is %s" % filekey)
        output = yield mapreduce_pipeline.MapreducePipeline(
            "EPN",
            "map_process_epn",
            "reduce_process_epn",
            "mapreduce.input_readers.RecordsReader",
            "mapreduce.output_writers.BlobstoreOutputWriter",
            mapper_params={
                 "files": filekey,                
            },
            reducer_params={
                 "mime_type": "text/plain",
            },
            shards=24)
        yield StoreOutput("EPN", filekey, output)
```

I have tried passing the file as a file object and as a string representation but neither works and there is not as much documentation on using different input/output reader/writers as I would like.

Any help or pointers will be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The sample application described [in the documentation](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/dataprocessing/helloworld) shows exactly how to do this. You need to upload your file to the blobstore, then pass the blob key to the mapreduce.